# Discrete mathematics logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

What is the negation for the question P <-> ~Q in logic.
Please give some suggestions how to solve this....
In logic how to find negation of the terms.

Comment: Consider the negation of $P\leftrightarrow R$ and evaluate it in $R=\neg Q$.

Comment: Use that $P\Leftrightarrow\neg Q\equiv\big(P\implies\neg Q\wedge\neg Q\implies P\big)$ and negate that expression.

Comment: Obviously : $P \leftrightarrow Q$. Check with truth table.

Answer (score 3):

I would do 
$$(P\iff \neg Q) \equiv [(P\to \neg Q) \land (\neg Q\to P)].$$
Hence, negating looks like this:
\begin{align*}
\neg(P\iff \neg Q) &\equiv \neg[(P\to \neg Q) \land (\neg Q\to P)] \\
&\equiv \neg(P\to \neg Q) \lor \neg(\neg Q\to P) \\
&\equiv (P\land \neg\neg Q) \lor (\neg Q \land \neg P) \\
&\equiv (P\land Q) \lor (\neg Q\land \neg P).
\end{align*}
I think you'll find this is also equivalent to $\neg(P\otimes Q),$ where $\otimes$ is the exclusive OR. Or even simpler: $P\iff Q.$

Comment: @MeesdeVries: Yep, just got that.